# Validating mandatory fields in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a C#/WPF application in which I've multiple views(say A,B,C etc.) and corresponding viewmodels.Developers will be adding a lot new views as well in the app in future.
Each view has various controls like textboxes, combobox,datetime picker,etc.

I'm trying to come up with a validation approach for required fields so that developers need to add minimum amount of code for validating the controls on the newly added views.

My current approach:

All my view models inherit from a base class called "ViewModelBase".I've added a new method called IsRequiredFieldValueBlank() in this class:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
        public bool IsRequiredFieldValueBlank(object inputObject)
        {
            bool isRequiredFieldValueBlank = true;
            try
            {
                var arrProperties = inputObject.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var prop in arrProperties)
                {
                    if (!prop.CanWrite)
                        continue;
                    if(prop.PropertyType.Name.ToUpper() == "STRING")
                    {                        
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.GetValue(inputObject).ToString()))
                        {
                            isRequiredFieldValueBlank = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //TBD:Handle exception here
            }
            return isRequiredFieldValueBlank;
        }
}
```

In my xaml code of View "A",I've the following code:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" TabIndex="1" Text="{Binding ProductDescription,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{DynamicResource RequiredFieldStyle}" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="3"  Margin="1,10,0,0" />
```

And in my MainWindoResources.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="RequiredFieldStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ViewModelBase.IsRequiredFieldValueBlank}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ViewModelBase.IsRequiredFieldValueBlank}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen" />
            </DataTrigger>            
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyTool.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Views/MainWindowResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

My questions:
1.Is this the correct approach?If yes, then I understand that the code wont work because the xaml is not passing the inpoObject to the IsRequiredFieldValueBlank() method in ViewModelBase class.
Could someone advise as to how to achieve that please?

2.Is there any other approach to handle this problem please?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a lot easier in the long run if you leverage the `Validator` static class for validation in combination with the `IDataErrorInfo` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces. Here's a very basic implementation expanding on PRISM's [`BindableBase`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs) class:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Error => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetValidationErrors());

    public bool IsValid => !GetValidationErrors().Any();

    public string this[string columnName] =>
        GetValidationErrors().FirstOrDefault(result => result.MemberNames.Contains(columnName))?.ErrorMessage;

    protected IEnumerable<ValidationResult> GetValidationErrors()
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(this);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        Validator.TryValidateObject(this, context, results, true);

        return results;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

You don't really need the RequiredFieldStyle file then, as well. Validation can be done like this:

```
public class ViewModelExample : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _myString;

    // do validation with annotations and IValidateableObject
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string MyString
    {
        get { return _myString; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _myString, value); }
    }
}
```

Just check the `IsValid` property to see if the object is valid before saving.